# Java TicTacToe game winCondition?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, tic-tac-toe

How would I make a win condition to my tic-tac-toe game? I need to also make it so when the player is done, that it will ask them if they want to play again. If you figure out a way, can you please tell me why that is so. Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class game extends JFrame{

    JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[9];
    private String mark = "";
    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new game();
    }

    public game(){

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();

        // Sets buttons on the screen
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            buttons[i] = new JButton(mark);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(handler);
            gameWindow.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        // Sets the looks of the window
        gameWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        gameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameWindow.setSize(300,300);
        gameWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            JButton click = (JButton) event.getSource();

            if(count % 2 == 0){
                mark = "X";
                click.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }else{
                mark = "O";
                click.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }

            click.setText(mark);
            click.setEnabled(false);


            System.out.println(count + "\n" + (count % 2));
            count++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you keeping track where all the Xs and Os are placed?

Comment: You have to loop through your buttons. It would probably be easier to implement and understand the logic is the buttons were in a 2-D, [3][3] array.

Comment: @jschabs This is done with `click.setText(mark)`, mixing model and view....

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to find out the winner.

I have mentioned all the winning positions. You have to check all the position on each click.

```
public String getWinner() {
    int[][] winPositions = new int[][] { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }, 
                                         { 0, 3, 6 }, { 1, 4, 7 }, { 2, 7, 8 }, 
                                         { 0, 4, 8 }, { 2, 4, 6 } };

    for (int[] positions : winPositions) {
        if (buttons[positions[0]].getText().length() > 0
                && buttons[positions[0]].getText().equals(buttons[positions[1]].getText())
                && buttons[positions[1]].getText().equals(buttons[positions[2]].getText())) {
            return buttons[positions[0]].getText();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

Add it in your `actionPerformed()` method in the end.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        ...

        String winner = getWinner();
        if (winner != null) {
            System.out.println(winner + " is winner");
            gameWindow.dispose();
        }
    }
```